# What is the reason req.body is displayed as undefined?

Tags: node.js, post, body-parser

Hi i am making a blog with node js. And now I am implementing the function to write a post, but there is a problem in this process.

new.ejs is a screen for creating a post.

new.ejs

```
<div>
      <h2> new post </h2>
      <form action="/articles" method = "POST">
            <h4>title</h4>
            <input required type="text" name = "title" / class='form-control'><br>              
            <h4>description</h4>
            <textarea  name="description" class = 'form-control'></textarea><br>
            <h4>contents</h4>
            <textarea id="mytextarea" name="contents" rows = '10'></textarea>
            <a href="/" class ="btn btn-secondary">취소</a><button type = "submit" class="btn btn-primary">저장</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

and
article.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.send("article");
});

router.get("/new/home", function (req, res) {
  res.render("articles/index");
});

router.get("/new", function (req, res) {
  res.render("articles/new");
});

router.post("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.title);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here, when req.body.title is executed, req.body becomes undefined. And in the code editor window, a sentence stating that bordyParser has been deprecated appears as the middle line is drawn. How to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The EJS file is POSTing to /articles, but your POST route in the NodeJS is /.

To fix the 'body-parser is deprecated' messages, change the code as follows :-

```
...
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
...
```

to

```
...
app.use(express.urlencoded());
...
```

Body Parser is now part of Express itself.